# VBA Remove Underscore from recordset column name when cell containing column name has a line break in it

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

When retrieving the column names from a recordset, if a column header has a break in the string, for example: ("Column vbNewLine Name") or 
("Column 
Name") 
the code below returns an underscore in the string variable, and would now look like "Column_Name".

I'm trying to match headers from multiple workbooks, and this changes the strings from a potential match.

How can I return the column name with no underscore if there is a line break in the cell?

Also, keep in mind, a simple replace wouldn't work as some column headers could contain an underscore.

```
Dim ado As Object
Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With ado
    .Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1""; Mode=Read;"
    With .OpenSchema(20)
        Dim table As String
        Dim rs As Object
        table = .Fields("TABLE_NAME")
        Set rs = ado.OpenSchema(4, Array(Empty, Empty, table))
        rs.MoveLast
        While Not rs.BOF
            Debug.Print rs!COLUMN_NAME
            rs.MovePrevious
        Wend
    End With
End With
```

Comment: You have to loop through the collection of columns and change their names by replacing `vbNewLine` with underscore. That's all!

Comment: How would I identify if a column has a line break?

Comment: You could use the Instr function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function